# Magento - Aheadworks blog extension WYSIWYG editor

Tags: magento

i've installed the blog extension from Aheadworks, which is supposed to use the native WYSIWYG editor that comes with Magento 1.4.* but the editor does not show up. The editor shows up on CMS pages and Static Blocks but not with this extension. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the extension was not compatible with Magento 1.4. They do have an upgrade now but the default TinyMCE editor that comes with Magento 1.4 messes up the image URLs.

Note: This is not an issue with the extension. The URL issue happens with CMS pages and Static Blocks too